# Generating XML from T-SQL, but unable to group siblings by parent

Tags: xml, t-sql, grouping, siblings

I am trying to generate a XML file of product support files to upload into WordPress via "WP All Import". I am unable to figure out how to phrase my XML PATH expression to group the resources (as siblings) under a single parent (product SKU) element.

I've spent hours on MSDN and getting ...close... with the AUTO mode. My problem seems to be that it is ignoring the fact there's multiple PARENT listings I'm trying to merge the data from.  Running SQL Server 17 (developer).

OK, I'm stymied. I've written a sample set of code to illustrate the point, BUT IT WORKS. So why does this sample work, when the same sort of query doesn't on my production database?!? NOTE: The following WAS supposed to illustrate the failure. But IT WORKS. Gaaarh!!!

```
-- Populate Products table
CREATE table ##product 
(
     id INT NOT NULL,
     sku VARCHAR(10),
)

INSERT INTO ##product (id, sku)
VALUES (1, 'Item1'),
       (2, 'Item2'), 
       (3, 'Item3');

-- Populate resources table
CREATE table ##support 
(
     id INT NOT NULL,
     doc VARCHAR(30),
     doctype VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO ##support (id, doc, doctype)
VALUES (1, 'Item 1 Instructions', 'PDF'),
       (2, 'Item 1 Drawings', 'PDF'),
       (3, 'Item 1 Software', 'ZIP'),
       (4, 'Company Info', 'PDF'),
       (5, 'Item 2 Instructions', 'PDF'),
       (6, 'Item 1.1 Instructions', 'PDF'),
       (7, 'Item 2 an 3 Software', 'ZIP');

-- Populate Items support library
CREATE TABLE ##library 
(
     id INT NOT NULL,
     product_id INT,
     support_id INT
)

INSERT INTO ##library (id, product_id, support_id)
VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3),
       (4, 1, 4), (5, 1, 6), (6, 2, 5),
       (7, 2, 4), (8, 3, 7), (9, 2, 7);

--Join up the key (product_id) against the library to get a list of the resources it uses:
DECLARE @xmldata XML 

SET @xmldata = (
          SELECT
              prod.sku AS [product.SKU],
              sup.doc AS [support.DOCUMENT],
              sup.doctype AS [support.DOCTYPE]
          FROM
              ##product AS prod
          LEFT JOIN 
              ##library AS lib ON lib.product_id = prod.id
          RIGHT JOIN
              ##support AS sup ON lib.support_id = sup.id
          ORDER BY
              prod.sku
          FOR XML auto, ROOT('DOCS'), type)

SELECT @xmldata AS returnXML
```

Results with almost PERFECT output data! Sample data works, but it SUCKS with real. I have my parent node SKU, with all sibling-children support items. GREAT!

```
<DOCS>
  <prod product.SKU="Item1">
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 1 Instructions" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 1 Drawings" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 1 Software" support.DOCTYPE="ZIP" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Company Info" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 1.1 Instructions" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
  </prod>
  <prod product.SKU="Item2">
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 2 Instructions" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup sup support.DOCUMENT="Company Info" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 2 and 3 Software" support.DOCTYPE="ZIP" />
  </prod>
  <prod product.SKU="Item3">
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 2 and 3 Software" support.DOCTYPE="ZIP" />
  </prod>
</DOCS>
```

But when I apply this method to my real data...(see below)

```
DECLARE @xmldata xml
SET @xmldata = (
  SELECT
   prod.sku AS [product.SKU],
      docs.name AS [lib.DOCUMENT],
      libtypes.name AS [lib.DOCNAME],
      lib.type AS [lib.DOCTYPE]
  From
      cat_products AS prod
       LEFT JOIN cat_product_docs AS docs ON docs.product_id = prod.product_id
      LEFT JOIN cat_product_library AS lib ON lib.id = docs.library_id
      LEFT JOIN cat_product_library_types AS libtypes ON libtypes.type_id = lib.type
  WHERE
       (lib.active = 1) AND  --filtering out for only active data
       (docs.active = 1) AND
       (prod.product_id = 210 OR  --limiting my output dataset
        prod.product_id = 224)
  ORDER BY prod.sku
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('DOCS'), TYPE)
SELECT @xmldata AS returnXml
```

Failing Results (no longer siblings):

```
<DOCS>
    <prod product.SKU="74HC86">
        <docs lib.DOCUMENT="74HC86 Datasheet">
            <libtypes lib.DOCNAME="Datasheet">
                <lib lib.DOCTYPE="1"/>
            </libtypes>
        </docs>
        <docs lib.DOCUMENT="74HC86 Block Diagram">
            <libtypes lib.DOCNAME="Datasheet">
                <lib lib.DOCTYPE="1"/>
            </libtypes>
        </docs>
    </prod>
    <prod product.SKU="ATMega8L">
        <docs lib.DOCUMENT="Atmel ATmega8(L) Summary PDF Datasheet">
            <libtypes lib.DOCNAME="Datasheet">
                <lib lib.DOCTYPE="1"/>
            </libtypes>
        </docs>
        <docs lib.DOCUMENT="Atmel ATmega8(L) PDF Datasheet">
            <libtypes lib.DOCNAME="Datasheet">
                <lib lib.DOCTYPE="1"/>
            </libtypes>
        </docs>
    </prod>
</DOCS>
```

Weirdly, I'm finding "FOR XML AUTO" gives me what I'm looking for in the "Sample data set", where a variation of "FOR XML PATH" works better for the 2nd set (but STILL doesn't group by the parent node product.SKU).

I've spend 15 hours on this puzzle and been staring at it too long. Most likely something wrong in my join? Why does "XML Auto" work perfectly on my demo data, but fail on my real data?

Comment: Definitely has something to do the with extra "LEFT JOIN"s... Deleting the extra joins makes it behave closer to desired.... Time to play with nested SELECTs

Answer (score 0):

After staring at it, a co-worker asked why I didn't just finish creating a giant garbage table that contained all the XML fields I wanted indexed against the single SKU master field. Doing this let me do a simple 1-to-many query which the XML AUTO was able to repack into the list sorted like I wanted.

Lesson here is not to use multiple joins if  you are expecting the ALIAS function to be what the FOR XML feature to index by. It's indexing against the tables in the FROM. (And no, the "INDEX PATH" didn't work as much as it looked like it should have been listening to the alias fields).

Answer (score 0):

That is the reason why I'd never use `AUTO` with `FOR XML`. The recommended mode is `PATH`, as it allows the highest control over your output.

Grouped / Nested XML nodes are achieved with a *correlated sub-query*. Try something along this (against your sample data provided in your question):

```sql
DECLARE @xmldata XML 

SET @xmldata = 
(
    SELECT p.sku AS [@product.SKU]
          ,(
            SELECT s.doc AS [@support.DOCUMENT]
                  ,s.doctype AS [@support.DOCTYPE]
            FROM ##library l
            INNER JOIN ##support s ON l.support_id=s.id
            WHERE l.product_id=p.id --This will fetch the correlated support rows only
            --you can add an ORDER BY-clause to get your support rows in a given order          
            FOR XML PATH('sup'),TYPE
           ) 
    FROM ##product p
    FOR XML PATH('prod'),ROOT('DOCS'),TYPE
)

SELECT @xmldata AS returnXML
```

the result

```
<DOCS>
  <prod product.SKU="Item1">
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 1 Instructions" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 1 Drawings" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 1 Software" support.DOCTYPE="ZIP" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Company Info" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 1.1 Instructions" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
  </prod>
  <prod product.SKU="Item2">
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Company Info" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 2 Instructions" support.DOCTYPE="PDF" />
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 2 an 3 Software" support.DOCTYPE="ZIP" />
  </prod>
  <prod product.SKU="Item3">
    <sup support.DOCUMENT="Item 2 an 3 Software" support.DOCTYPE="ZIP" />
  </prod>
</DOCS>
```